# java Files.readAllBytes(image.png) doesn't work

Tags: java, image, arrays

I was trying to read from file and then write to other file. I use code bellow to do so.

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file1);

Writer Writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file2), "UTF-8"));
for(int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++)
     Writer.write(bytes[i]);
Writer.close();
```

But when I change file1 to picture.png and file2 to picture2.png, this method doesn't work and I can't open picture2.png using image viewer.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: start by checking the length of the files?

Comment: Length of picture2.png is bigger than picture1.png. Checked in hexeditor.

Comment: Show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: also, bufferedwritter.write take an int, writes a char. It is designed for use with strings. Use `FileOutputStream` directly. it has a `write(byte)`  method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writers are for writing text, possibly in different formats (ie utf-8 / 16, etc). For writing raw bytes, don't use writers. Just use (File)OutputStreams.

It is truly as simple as

```
byte[] bytes = ...;
FileOutputStream fos = ...;
fos.write(bytes);
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers explain why what you have potentially fails.

I'm curious why you're already using one Java NIO method, but not others? The library already has methods to do this for you.

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file1);
Files.write(file2, bytes, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW); // or relevant OpenOptions
```

or

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file2); // or buffered
Files.copy(file1, out);
out.close();
```

or

```
Files.copy(file1, file2, options);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Writer.write()` doesn't take a `byte`. It takes a `char`, which is variable size, and often bigger than one byte.

But once you've got the whole thing read in as a `byte[]`, you can just use `Files.write()` to send the whole array to a file in much the same way that you read it in:

```
Files.write(filename, bytes);
```

This is the more modern NIO idiom, rather than using an `OutputStream`.

It's worth reading [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html).